# Issues with displaying time results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code to take in a running pace value (min/km), convert it to speed (km/hr) and then depending on the slope gradient and whether the direction of travel is up or downhill the lost speed is calculated (km/hr). The new running speed is then displayed along with the new running pace and the time your route is altered by.

The issue is when I input a pace such as  3:50 (min/km) with an uphill slope of 1% the new running pace is 3:60 (min/km). How do I get the script to tick over to 4:00 in this case? Also if 3:55 (min/km) is input the new running pace given is 4:5 (min/km) when it should read as 4:05 (min/km). How do i edit this?

The script is:

```
    import math

    print('Q1')
    SurveyPace = input("Running Pace (min/km): \n "). split(":")                    
    SurveyPace = float(SurveyPace[0])*60 + float(SurveyPace[1])                                     


    Speed = 3600/SurveyPace                                                                         

    print("Original running speed =","%.2f" % round(Speed,2), 'km/hr')
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")

    print('Q2')
    SlopeDirection = int(input('For Uphill press 1 \nFor Downhill press 2 \n '))                    

    print("--------------------------------------------------------")

    print('Q3')
    SlopeGradient = float(input('Percentage gradient(without the % symbol)?\n '))                   

    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    print('CALCULATED RESULTS')
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    if SlopeDirection == 1:
            Change = - 0.65 * SlopeGradient                                                                 
    if SlopeDirection == 2:
            Change = + 0.35 * SlopeGradient                                                         
    print ('This route alters your speed by \n', Change,'km/hr')
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")

    AdjustedSpeed = Speed + Change                                                                   
    AdjustedPace = 3600/AdjustedSpeed                                                                
    PaceSecs = round(AdjustedPace % 60)
    PaceMins = math.floor(AdjustedPace/60)

    print("New running speed is \n","%.2f" % round(AdjustedSpeed,2), 'km/hr')                          
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    print("New running pace is \n", str(PaceMins) + ":" + str(PaceSecs), 'min/km')                     
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
    print("This route alters your pace by \n", int(PaceSecs + (PaceMins*60)) - SurveyPace, "sec/km")   #Prints the time change incured
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

Thanks

Comment: There are a number of problems here, including I think in your logic - why is `SurveyPace` equal to the number of minutes multiplied by 60 *plus* the number of kilometers? That doesn't equal anything.  Also, please look into the Python PEP8 style guide; your use of mixed case variable names isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the built-in function [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
# Round the AdjustedPace to seconds                                                            
AdjustedPace = round(3600/AdjustedSpeed)

minutes, seconds = divmod(AdjustedPace, 60)
print(minutes)
print(seconds)
```

This will lead to:

```
#Pace = 3:50
#4
#0

#Pace = 3:55
#4
#5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `timedelta` objects from datetime:

```
import datetime
inp = raw_input('Enter your pace in minutes per km (min:km):')
mins, kms = inp.split(':')
time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(mins))
```

If you enter 60 minutes, for example, will give you:

```
> time
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

And then you can perform math operations on it and it stays correct:

```
> time / 2
datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)
```

Or if you want minutes just divide it by 60, hours divide it by 3600.  You can also add and subtract timedelta objects from each other, or from datetime objects if you want timestamps.  Or if your divisor leaves a remainder:

```
> new = time / 17
> new
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
> new.seconds
200
> new.microseconds
764706
```

Which you could then use to round if you wanted.  It's a good way to make sure your time always stays accurate.